# How can I query a Postgres DateRange with a single date?

Tags: django, django-models, django-postgresql

I am using `django.contrib.postgres.field.DateRangeField` as described [here][1].

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_range = DateRangeField()
```

How to I query this model to return all `date_range` with a lower bound greater than today?

I tried:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
MyModel.objects.filter(date_range__gt=today)
```

But this results in `operator does not exist: daterange > date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyModel.objects.filter(date_range__contains=today)`